# YII PHP nested foreach error

Tags: php, yii, foreach, frameworks, nested

I have some error here
I want to combine data from 2 query using nested `foreach` and save the data in a array called result but there is an error `Trying to get property of non-object` in these part of code : `'id_product'=>$detail_result->ID`,
can anyone help me?

i'm still new using  yii framework php

here is my code

$result = array();

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->condition = 'date_time >= :start and date_time <= :end';
        $criteria->order = 'date_time';
        $criteria->params = array(':start' => $_POST['tanggal']['start'] ,':end' => $_POST['tanggal']['end']);

        $checkIn = CheckIn::model()->findAll($criteria);

        foreach($checkIn as $entry) {
            $sql = "select * from check_in_detail where ID_check_in = $entry->ID";
            $detail_results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

            foreach($detail_results as $detail_result)
            {
                 $result [] = array(
                     'tanggal'=>$entry->date_time,
                    'id_product'=>$detail_result->ID,
                     'total'=>$detail_result->total,
                     'id_distributor'=>$entry->iDDistributor->name,
                     'other'=>$entry->description,
                 );
             }
         }
```

is anyone can help?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your accessing to `$detail_result` variable,

function `queryAll()` will bring back an **array of arrays**, NOT an array of objects!

change your code to below :

```
             $result [] = array(
                 'tanggal'=>$entry['date_time'],
                 'id_product'=>$detail_result['ID'],
                 'total'=>$detail_result['total'],
                 ...  
             );
```

(btw you could just var_dump your variable to see exactly what it contains)